# How to access alamofire response

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm new to iOS and I have some Swift code in app that's supposed to switch cases depending on the error message that I receive from the server. The message is wrapped and I'm having trouble getting to it. Here's the code

```
func sendAlamofireRequest(submissionURL: URL, parameters: Parameters, chosenTracker: String) -> String {

    var outputMessage = ""

    Alamofire.request(submissionURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseString() {
        response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful...\(String(describing: response.value))")

            print("response value: \(String(response.value!))")
            switch response.value {
            case "error_none"?:
                outputMessage = "No matching Group Code. If you are having trouble, please go to \nhttps://app.phillyscientists.com"
                break
            case "error_tooManyIDs"?:
                outputMessage = "Error, please contact developer."
                break
            case "error_noGroupIDReceived"?:
                outputMessage = "Try Again."
                break
            default:

                let JSONResponse : JSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: response.result.value!)

                //uncomment this section for debugging
                //                        print("=================<JSON RESP>=================");
                //                        print(JSONResponse)
                //                        print("=================</JSON RESP/>=================");
                //
                let teacherNameGot = self.parseJSONData(json: JSONResponse, trackerValuePassed: chosenTracker)
                self.saveJSONDataToUserDefaults(teacher: teacherNameGot)

//                    outputMessage = "Logged In Successfully!"

                break
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            outputMessage = String(error.localizedDescription)
            print(outputMessage)

        }
    }
    return outputMessage
}
```

Here's the output from console:

```
Validation Successful...Optional("{\"Error\":\"error_none\"}")
response value: Optional("{\"Error\":\"error_none\"}")
```

How do I get to the value so that the switch case actually starts working?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the output is in Json, so i'll need to map it into an object(or class,whatever you call it). If you think its not worth it, you can convert it into an Dictionary, i think it will work as well

Comment: I understand but maybe that's an overkill to do that since I'm using it just one time? Can I do something like response.value.Errror??

Answer (score 2):

you can use Alamofire method `.responseJSON` which will give you an http object that has several attributes like `request` and `response`. Take this code as an example:

```
Alamofire.request("https://your-service-url.com/api", method: .post, parameters: paremeters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (data) in

            guard let statusCode = data.response?.statusCode, statusCode == 200, let result = data.result.value as? [[String: Any]] else{
                print("Error with HTTP status \(data.response?.statusCode ?? 0)")

                return
            }
            var events : [Event] = []
            result.forEach({ (rawEvent) in
                events.append(Event(from: rawEvent))
            })


            handler(events, statusCode)
    }
```

Notice how I play there with the objects that `.responseJSON` provides, and how I get the resulting array from the service by accessing `data.result.value` (that being said this will depend on the data structure of your service response)

Answer (score 0):

@Gustavo caiafa is right, Mapping it to JSON did the trick. Here's the code for anyone who gets stuck on something similar:

```
Alamofire.request(submissionURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseString() { (response) in

        let outputResponseJSON : JSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: response.result.value!)
        let outputResponseText = JSON(outputResponseJSON)["Error"].stringValue

        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful...\(String(describing: response.value))")

            print("response value: \(String(describing: String(outputResponseText)))")
            switch outputResponseText {
            case "error_none":
                outputMessage = "No matching Group Code. If you are having trouble, please go to \nhttps://app.phillyscientists.com"
                print(outputMessage)
                break
            case "error_tooManyIDs":
                outputMessage = "Error, please contact developer."
                print(outputMessage)
                break
            case "error_noGroupIDReceived":
                outputMessage = "Try Again."
                print(outputMessage)
                break
            default:

                let JSONResponse : JSON = JSON.init(parseJSON: response.result.value!)
```

The answer is using SwiftyJSON for the outputResponseJSON and outputResponseText values.